# Digital Advisory Services for Rural Farmers using ML, GIS and RS

Tags: python, open-source-gis, jupyter-notebook, open-data-cube

I am working on a GIS-based project to help with the delivery of advisory services to rural farmers. This project is demanding the use of Open-Data Cube and the SandBox environment. It is more like a proof-of-concept.
I am having problems with how to set up my own (local) sandbox and also, how to get started with using the Open-Data-Cube resources.
May I get any help and resource recommendations?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. This is not a discussion site rather a problem-solving platform. For tutorials and resources you can use google or other discussion forums. Kindly take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

ODC "Sandboxes" are not intended for local deployment - they are cloud-deployed environments intended to support large numbers of users accessing the same pool of indexed EO imagery.

You can set up a local ODC environment, but this will entail you building and maintaining an database index of all possible data you may want to access.

Existing Sandbox deployments are intended to support proof-of-concept work so that researchers do not need to expend a lot of effort and learning up front to manage their own data index and can concentrate on their actual analysis. I would strongly recommend this path, at least initially.

If the sandbox environment supplied by Digital Earth Australia is not appropriate for your needs (e.g. because your farmers are not in Australia), then the EASI-EO team at CSIRO can give you a price for setting up and administering a custom sandbox-like environment for project.

Whichever approach you settle on, you can get support on the ODC Slack.  Get an invite by entering your email address here: https://slack.opendatacube.org/